# Preview Changes button missing on custom post type page since updating to 3.4

Tags: plugin-development, previews

Any idea why when I'm on post.php of my custom post type page I no longer see the Preview Changes button?

I have checked on an old installation and it shows on WordPress version 3.3 but not 3.4.

The custom post page has this HTML:

[image]

A normal post page has:

[image]

Why is my custom post page missing the div preview-action in the latest version of WordPress?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I run through exact same issue. Later I come to know that custom post type I created was not public and hence it does not have 'Preview Changes' button visible.

Prior version of Wordpress was displaying that button but it seems they have fixed it now.

To fix it, make sure you set '**public**' to '**true**' in array of arguments you are passing to '**register_post_type function**'.

Hope it will help!

Neerav

Comment: I just ran into this, so first thank you for your answer it pointed me in the right direction. However my solution was a bit different, the setting I needed to set to true in my CPT registration was 'publicly_queryable' => true. I was able to leave 'public' => false but had to change the other one to get the button to show. Just in case someone else finds this post and has a similar setup for their CPT. Thanks again for the clear answer.